# abp entity not exist: AbpEntityChangeSets

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

Using ABP Core I always stayed up to date with the newest NUGET packages.
What I forgot was to create migrations. I just moved to ABP4.2.0 when i realized that my last EF snapshot was from ABP3.5.0.

I created a new migration completing with this warning:

> An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data.
>   Please review the migration for accuracy.

Then I tried to update-database. I got this exception as a result:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the
>   object "AbpEntityChangeSets" because it does not exist or you do not
>   have permissions.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite,
>   String methodName)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2
>   parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action)

Interestingly the Entity "AbpEntityChangeSets" was already defined in the snapshot from April 2018. But the entity was never to be found in the Database.

Help much appreciated! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Run the migrations...

Comment: how do i run migrations if not by executing update-database?

Comment: Revert your snapshot and run the migrations properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some prior ABP db-migration has been edited manually

So we created a new ABP Template with v4.2.0 and re-used its db-migrations.